# Get Input value from Edittext which generated dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have to create n `EditText` where n is user input.

I could create it using `for` loop.

```
TableLayout tbl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout1);
    //table row
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
                new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //for set margin
        tableRowParams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
        tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
        tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        //text view
        TextView tv=new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Field "+(i+1));
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0070C0"));
        tv.setTextSize(26);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(100, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //add textview
        tr.addView(tv);
        //set layout params of edittext
        TableRow.LayoutParams etParams=
                new TableRow.LayoutParams
                (120,30);
        etParams.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);

        EditText et=new EditText(this);
        et.setLayoutParams(etParams);
        et.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_grey);
        et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
        tr.addView(et);
        tbl.addView(tr, tableRowParams);
    }
```

I got Layout

[image]

Let me know how to retrieve data from dymamically created EditTexts.

Comment: create loop for n times and in loop you can access all the text entered in edittext...

Comment: how to set and get ids?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to add editText

```
//list to store edittexts
List<EditText> etList = new ArrayList<EditText>();
TableLayout tbl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(CurrentActivity.this);  
    TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
        new TableLayout.LayoutParams
        (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
    EditText et=new EditText(CurrentActivity.this);
    et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    et.setId(Id+i);//string+i
    //add et to table row
    tr.addView(et);
    //add table row to table            
    tbl.addView(tr, tableRowParams);
    //add edittext to list
    etList.add(et);
}
```

to get values

```
for (EditText et : etList) {
    System.out.println(et.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: point to be noted: List<EditText> etList = new ArrayList<EditText>();  
and etList.add(et); Thank you @MadDeveloper :)

Answer (score 1):

As you create the EditTexts you should store them in an Array or in a List

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    EditText myEditText = new EditText();
    myEditTextList.add(myEditText);
}
```

After this you can just iterate over your list and get the strings from the EditTexts:

```
for (EditText editText : myEditTextList) {
    String text = editText.getText().toString();
    Log.d(TAG, text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you layout xlm create LinearLayout

in Activity onCreate method find that layout

```
containerLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);

//now create loop
for(int i=0; i<=arraysize; i++){

EditText editText+String.valueof(i) = new EditText(getBaseContext());
    containerLayout.addView(editText+String.valueof(i));
      editText.setGravity(Gravity.Left);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) editText.getLayoutParams();
      layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
      layoutParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
       // layoutParams.setMargins(23, 34, 0, 0);
     // RelativeLayout.LayoutParams()
       editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
       //if you want to identify the created editTexts, set a tag, like below
     editText+String.valueof(i).setTag("EditText" + i);

}
```